# Data Architecture: Deduplication of product catalogs

Tags: database-design, architecture, duplicates, hbase, record-linkage

I'm thinking out my strategy for **merging (and de-duplicating)** multiple catalogs of products.

I'll be using a no-sql database, and need to **query N catalogs** of partially overlapping products.

Certain aspects such as categorization, tags, descriptions, etc need to be **normalized**, and I need to track what catalogs contain each unique item (**de-duplication of products** in each catalog, by UPC for example).

> My current thought is to import the individual catalogs into their own
>   tables, then use self-built algorithms to identify "similar" items,
>   perform normalization, then create a final "Master" table which
>   contains the normalized & de-duplcated data - (the master-record
>   values would be copied from whichever catalog or mix of catalogs it's
>   chosen from & contain links to which catalogs contain that item).

*I wonder what other thoughts exist on the subject? What areas of research should I look into to better educate myself?*

Comment: De-duplication and normalization are concepts that apply to relational databases, and don't translate very well to NoSQL.  Remember, NoSQL implementations don't support joins, which makes it extremely difficult to query fully normalized data.

Comment: I think you take the terms of De-duplication and normalization in the sense that they are used in a relational database. In this case, de-duplication of a product catalog and normalization of features such as categorization are higher level concepts, not related to the strict tenants of SQL schemas. The NoSQL approach is considered mostly due to the need to execute some larger clustering, classification and/or recommendation algorithms on a large data set. In my current thinking, there would actually be quite a bit of data duplication in order to fit the NoSQL DB model effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't supply a lot of details but from what I understand, if you'd be using HBase you can do the following:

1. write all the data into hbase in the original formats or close to
   that
2. write a map/reduce to sort things out:

   2.1. in the map phase normalize and emit the potential keys

   2.2. int he reduce phase (where you get all the records with the same key) produce the master record
3. export master record to where you'd like

Comment: Yeh, this is the jist of it. I'm really just reaching out to try to learn what I don't know yet, just see if there are tools, frameworks, and communities that I might not be aware of yet which focus on these challenges. I'm pretty familiar with hadoop, hbase, and mahout.

Comment: I didn't state that clearly but what I meant is that you should write everything into a single HBase table and not multiple ones. HBase support poly-structured data easily and you may be able to resolve some of the duplicates on the map side (using combiners).

Answer (score 1):

There are some local companies here that generate Sql schemas nightly/weekly from NoSql for reporting purposes.

From what I understand the approach used is by them is exactly how you have described. I believe that your data set is very large you shouldn't have any issues with that strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a huge area of research since the 1940s (no, honestly) under the name [record linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) (but unfortunately it's also known by many other names, like "identity resolution", "data matching", "merge/purge", etc etc). There's a huge amount to learn here, and people have developed lots of techniques and tools that you can use. I would strongly recommend that you familiarize yourself with these before trying to write something yourself.

Note that a key problem is going to be performance. You basically have to compare all record pairs (which is O(n^2)), and you should ideally use fuzzy string comparators (which are all slow). That alone is a good reason for using a tool that already has the performance problem solved, and can also provide the string comparators etc.

The Wikipedia link has references to both research and tools. I strongly recommend looking at it.

Anyway, if you want to learn more, the first book (that I know of) on the subject was published earlier this year: [Data Matching, by Peter Christen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642311636). Two good overview papers are Duplicate Record Detection: A Survey (Elmagarmid, Ipeirotis, and Verykios), and Overview of Record Linkage and Current Research Directions (William Winkler). I'd post links, but the anti-spam won't let me. I did a presentation on this earlier this year that gives a brief overview of the problems, research, and solutions (it's on slideshare, title "Linking data without common identifiers").